# disqus comment box overlap with tumblr page

Tags: tumblr, disqus

I successfully performed a manual installation of disqus comments on my tumblr.

However, when I click on an individual post and scroll down the page, the disqus comment box shows up before the end of my post, so there is an overlap of text with the comment box.

Here is an example of this happening on a page of my blog: http://katmanduu.tumblr.com/post/108878690808/memories

I am new to this so would appreciate any help to fix it. Perhaps something went wrong with the manual disqus install. I pretty much followed the exact instructions and copied/pasted how to install it from here: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/758168-tumblr-manual-installation-instructions

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes in your css you have a height set on the post container of 500px, so the discuss stuff is appearing beneath 500px.

If you change this property in the css it should fix the issue. Just remove the height property from:

```
 #layer {
   height: 500px;
 }
```

I've tested it in the browser and it appears to fix it in Chrome.

Comment: @katmanduu would you mind voting on the answer if it helped you? Thanks